# when move the rig, the mesh becomes twisted

Tags: mesh, rigging, rigify

I rigged using rigify. There were no other problems, but if I lifted or lowered the rig on the front leg,
It gets twisted like the picture.

Here is a link to download my blend file:  https://www.mediafire.com/file/giuuckhc81g8uuh/rigging.blend/file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It most likely happens because the knee of the leg is not meant to bend backwards like in your rig. To fix it, switch the Rotation Axis of both front legs to X Manual.
Alternatively you can use the paw rig type.